# How to remove this special character?

Tags: python, string

I was trying to unify the lines in my file when I observed the following:

word1 word2
word1 word2

I did not understand why these lines were not combined so I opened the file in vim and used `:set list` to see if there are any special characters and I found this:

```
 word1 <feff>word2
 word1 word2
```

I am not sure how to clean this word in Python. Any suggestions on what character might be and how this can be cleaned?

Comment: feff is 'ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE'.

Comment: @gladoscc: Oh! Googling shows it is a character that goes by the name BOM character. I have no idea where it crept into my file from!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

U+FEFF is the [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark) character, which should only occur at the start of a document. In documents, [it should be treated as a `ZERO WIDTH NON-BREAKING SPACE`](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom6). If this causes issues, you can remove it like any other character:

```
>>> s = u'word1 \ufeffword2'
>>> s = s.replace(u'\ufeff', '')
>>> s
u'word1 word2'
```

<sub>(In Python 3.1 or 3.2, drop the `u` in front of strings)</sub>

Comment: Thank You. This might sound silly but it gives me this error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: @Legend That's because you're incorrectly dealing with non-ASCII characters. Use `s = sBytes.decode('UTF-8')` to decode a UTF-8 string. Test your code with inputs containing `ä` or `Σ`!

Comment: @Legend: you have to open your file using codecs: `lines = codecs.open('file.txt', 'r', 'utf-8')`, assuming your file is in utf-8.

Comment: @Legend On a related note, if you're not sure about the distinction between bytes and string, you may want to [read](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/printerFriendly/articles/Unicode.html) [up](http://diveintopython3.org/strings.html#byte-arrays) [on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-byte-array-to-python-string) that.

Comment: Actually, this solved the problem: `w = w.replace('\xef\xbb\xbf', '')` Thank you for the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `mytext.split(string.whitespace)` ?

Comment: Oh.. My text is separated with a `$`

Comment: Then you can do `mytext.split('$')`.

Comment: Oh that's not what I meant :) I meant I was splitting it using a different token. The replace with `\xed\xbb\xbf` solved my problem.