# Error zapier with ufeff

Tags: byte-order-mark, zapier

I integrated Zapier into my application. At first, everything was working. I was able to create some Zaps and receive some information. After a few days, I created a new Zap, but this time it didn't work. I got in touch with Zapier's support and they informed me that the problem is with the ID I was providing them. It contains some extra characters.

```
`\ufeff{"id":"23"}`
```

Does anyone know what I can do to solve this problem? When I test with Postman, I don't see any extra characters.

Comment: Just to be clear, the unexpected characters are: \ufeff? Are the backticks `` unexpected characters as well? If you just put them there to show that it's code you should remove them. The block formatting already makes that clear.

Comment: @JoeyHarwood The problem is that for me these unexpected characters do not appear. When I return this data to Zapier, I do not see these characters, nor the tests I did for Postman. They appear only to Zapier, which receives the data via Python. I tried to solve it by changing the file's encoding and even then I did not succeed.

Comment: Okay, I understand that part. You provided \`\ufeff{"id":"23"}\` as the string that Zapier support is seeing. I expect you meant that \ufeff{"id":"23"} is the string that Zapier support is seeing, but you added the ` characters for presentation purposes. Is that correct?

Comment: I think you may be able to find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786609/how-to-remove-this-special-character

Comment: @JoeyHarwood But in this case the treatment is being done in Python, where it receives the data. In my case I have to do the processing in PHP, where I send the data to Zapier.

Comment: That's fine, from that page you can learn that \ufeff is a character that's invisible in text editors. You want to remove it in php so googling php ufeff brings you this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18029992/how-do-i-remove-a-ufeff-character-in-my-webpage-scripts/18030050

Comment: @JoeyHarwood I'll look, thanks for the help.