# Got an extra space in the head of line in python3, which can not remove with strip()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I have a file contains string "1234" and I save it with "utf-8".
Then I open it with python3:

```
with open('test2.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        print("len: ", len(line))
        print(line[0])
        print(line[1])
```

I got this output:

```
len:  5

1
```

If I save it with "ANSI", there will be no extra space.
I have tried created it with UltraEdit and the space remains the same.

How can I remove the space?

Comment: Which space you're referring to?

Comment: what do u get when `print(repr(line[0])`

Comment: `line[0]` is a space and `line.strip(' ')` did not work

Comment: I got `'\ufeff'` with `print(repr(line[0])`, what is that??

Comment: Can not reproduce on windows 7. Saved as utf-8 with geany

Comment: It's a BOM, not a space.

Comment: @SikaiYao [How to remove this special character?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6786609)

Comment: Looks like you have a windows file, try `encoding="utf-8-sig"` so that python knows about the BOM

Comment: I tried ultraedit and save it without 'BOM'